# Expose angularJS services as APIs

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, api

I have an application which uses AngularJS as well as React components. I want to pass data between the 2 components. I have one service in angular which stores state data, and I want my react component to read this data.

I am looking for a way in which I can share data between these 2 components.
I would also like to know whether there is a way to expose my angular service using http (similar to a restful API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a reference to your angularjs component's scope (or rootScope or any scope in which you expose your shared data in), using const ngScope = window.angular.element('my-ng-comp').scope() in your react app.

Q&D way: window.ngStuff = someNgThing;

Remember if you change something in ng scope from the outside, ng change detection won't run, need to pass a setter or callback to the outside, in which you trigger it manually (with $scope.apply or $timeout etc).

To the other question, no there's no way to run an http server in the browser.

**Edit:** Made a plunk of a simple inter-app comms class based on RXJS BehaviorSubject. Something like this would be a cleaner way as the different apps don't need to know anything about each other:

```
var app1Comms = new Comms();
app1Comms.sharedState$.subscribe(state => log('App 1 received state', state));
app1Comms.setState({a:2}); 
...
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/4WvHeWriSyu5c0NqlCLS?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! Will I need to wrap my angular service as well?

Comment: Anything you want to have access to from the outside. A service would be good for that as they're "eternal" singletons, so you're not depending on a component that might not have the lifetime of the whole app.

Comment: Depending on the complexicity of your case, there may be better cleaner ways to do all this though, maybe like some global class outside both react and ng that'd let them both register to it and send messages to each other. But in a simple case this'll work fine :)

Comment: Edited my answer: a plunker to elaborate on my previous point :)